# Three tier java generics inheritance

Tags: java, generics

This is my current java class structure

```
Abstract TopClass <T extends Foo>
    display(T)

BottomSubClass extends TopClass <MyFoo>
     void display(MyFoo)
     {
         // display something
     }
```

…where `MyFoo` extends `Foo`.

This works fine, but now I want to introduce an abstract intermediary subclass between `TopClass` and `BottomSubClass` called `IntermediateSubClass`.

```
 Abstract TopClass <T extends Foo>
    display(T)    

 Abstract IntermediateSubClass<T extends Foo> extends TopClass 

 BottomSubClass extends IntermediateSubClass<MyFoo>
     void display(MyFoo)
     {
         // display something
     }
```

I now get compile errors in `BottomSubClass` indicating that the overridden 
method `void display(MyFoo)` needs to be declared in a superclass.
I also get a an error to implement method `void display(Foo)`.

Why doesn't the generic class parameter propagate down the class hierarchy—is there something wrong with my syntax in IntermediateSubClass?

I expected `BottomSubClass` to compile.

Comment: Shouldn’t that be `IntermediateSubClass<T extends Foo> extends TopClass<T>`? Not that it necessarily solves your problem.

Comment: Please post code that doesn’t have *other* compile errors than the one you are asking about. That will make it a lot easier for everyone. Thx.

Comment: `extends TopClass` without any generic types disables type checks and will confuse the compiler at least to the point that it will see `T = Object` in `TopClass`. This will lead to followup errors which sometimes can be quite confusing. Thus `extends TopClass<T>` should resolve your issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following passes compilation:

```
abstract class TopClass <T extends Foo> {
  abstract void display(T t);
}

abstract class IntermediateSubClass<T extends Foo> extends TopClass<T> {

}

class BottomSubClass extends IntermediateSubClass<MyFoo>
{
  void display(MyFoo t)
  {
    // display something
  }
}
```

Your problem was the definition of `IntermediateSubClass`, which extended the raw `TopClass` instead of `TopClass<T>`.